# operator= isn't called, segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading

I have a simple class Game that holds two fields, `int N` and `bool isVerbalOn`. I wrote an operator= (copy assignment operator) for this class, but when I try to use that operator= I get a "Segmentation fault(core dumped)" error, and the operator= isn't called, i.e. I don't see the "In game oeprator=" print. Classes and main class are attached below for you convinience:

**Game.h:**

```
#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Game {
    private:
        int N;
        bool isVerbalOn;
    public:
        Game(char* configurationFile); // implemented and works perfectly
        void init(); // implemented and works perfectly
        void play(); // empty implementation
        void printState(); // implemented
        void printWinner(); // emtpy implementation
        void printNumberOfTurns(); // empty implementation
        Game & operator=(const Game &game_);
        ~Game(); // implemented and works perfectly
};

#endif
```

**Game.cpp:**

```
#include "../include/Game.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

// .. functions implemented

Game &Game::operator=(const Game &game_) {
    cout << "Game operator=" << endl;
    if(this == &game_) {
        return *this;
    }
    N = game_.N;
    isVerbalOn = game_.isVerbalOn;
    return *this;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../include/Game.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char* configurationFile = argv[1];

    Game game = Game(configurationFile);
    game.init();
    Game initializedGame = game; // operator= isn't called
    game.play();

    cout << endl;
    cout << "----------" << endl;
    cout<<"Initial State:"<<endl;
    initializedGame.printState();
    cout<<"----------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Final State:"<<endl;
    game.printState();
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile compiled with no errors or warnings, and the output is:

```
----------
Initial State:
Deck: 2H 2S QD
Alice:2C 3D 3S JH QH KC AH 
Bob:3C JS QC KH KS AD AS 
Charlie:2D 3H JC JD QS KD AC 
----------
Final State:
Deck: 2H 2S QD
Alice:2C 3D 3S JH QH KC AH 
Bob:3C JS QC KH KS AD AS 
Charlie:2D 3H JC JD QS KD AC 
Game destructor
Deck destructor
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As you can see, the print in game operator= "Game operator=" should have been printed before anything else, which doesn't happen.

P.S. I checked many other questions about this on SOF and didn't find anything that helped me. Any helped is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: That line is initialization, not assignment.

Comment: `Game initializedGame = game;` calls the copy constructor, not the assignment operator.

Comment: `type name = something;` is never the assignment operator.

Comment: `Game game = Game(configurationFile);` Why not `Game game(configurationFile);`?

Comment: Wow okay I get it now, thanks!

Comment: If you share the code you have commented as "implemented and works perfectly" we might be able to spot why you get a seg fault

Comment: Present a [MCVE].

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand that, all the other code worked, tested, and even used valgrind to make sure the destructor works properly and there are no memory leaks. In this case I provided that code that's relevant to my question. I'll keep that in mind for future reference.

Comment: I suspect the other code you have tested doesn't work when an object has been copied - the code as posted provides a test that fails. Your outut says "Deck destructor... seg fault" - so something has made a `Deck ` somewhere - maybe the `Game` has one and we can't see the code from your listing

Comment: @doctorlove Once I implemented the copy constructor as suggested in the comments and answers everything else worked perfectly and there was no segmentation fault.

Comment: _"In this case I provided that code that's relevant to my question."_ No, you're not qualified to do that. Present a [MCVE]. If you haven't made one yet, you haven't finished debugging. _"I'll keep that in mind for future reference"_ Edit it in now please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Game initializedGame = game; // operator= isn't called
```

This will call copy consrtuctor.

Add the following copy constructor in your Game.cpp

```
Game(const Game &game_) {
    cout << "Game copy ctro" << endl;
    N = game_.N;
    isVerbalOn = game_.isVerbalOn;
}
```

Preferably

```
Game(const Game &game_):N(game_.N), isVerbalOn(game_.isVerbalOn)
{}
```

Comment: You really should be using a member initialization list in the copy constructor.

Comment: How will this differ from the default copy constructor?

Comment: Actually I implemented it with the initialization list, I don't understand C++ deep enough to understand the reason behind it but that seems the common convention.

Comment: @LironIlayev There are certain variables that can only be initialized in the initializer list.  Once you hit the constructor body anything that was not initialized in the initializer list gets default initialized and then you are just doing assignment in the body.

Answer (score 1):

```
Game initializedGame = game; // operator= isn't called
```

No, it wouldn't be.

That's a declaration and initialisation, invoking the copy constructor.

Despite what the `=` character looks like in this line, the assignment operator has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yep that's where I got it wrong, pretty new to C++, thanks!